# Список в динамической памяти

Tags: c++

На словах вроде бы всё понятно, а на практике не получается. Вот на этом примере и желательно с пояснением если можно:

```
#include <iostream.h> 
struct list 
{ 
 int data; 
 struct list *next; 
}; 
void main() 
{ 
 list *vsp; 
 // здесь нужно создать список, например из 5 элементов и задать значения 
 // информационным полям, потом вывести список на экран

 cout<<endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Другой способ (более универсальный):

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct st
{
    char name[10];
    int age;
    struct st *next;
};

void main()
{ 
    st * list = NULL; // Изначально пустой список
    st * temp; // Временная переменная

    // Добавление данных в список:
    while(1)
    {
        temp = (st*)malloc(sizeof(st));
        cout<<"enter data:"<<endl;
        cin>>temp->name>>temp->age;
        // Если введенный возраст < 0 то выход из цикла
        if(temp->age<0) { 
            free(temp); // освобождаем незадействованный элемент
            break;
        }
        // Добавляем новый элемент в _начало_ списка:
        temp->next = list;
        list = temp;
    }

    // Обход списка с выводом данных на экран:
    temp = list;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->name<<" "<<temp->age<<endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    // ...

    // Освобождение списка:
    while(list!=NULL)
    {
        temp = list->next; // Запоминаем указатель на следующий элемент
        free(list); // Освобождаем первый элемент
        list = temp; // Убираем освобожденный первый элемент из списка
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример:

```
void main()
{
    list* nodes=new list[5]; //Создаём сразу 5 элементов списка

    //Устанавливаем первый элемент
    nodes[0].data=3; //число
    nodes[0].next=nodes+1; //Указываем на следующий элемент

    //Второй элемент
    nodes[1].data=14;
    nodes[1].next=nodes+2;

    //Третий элемент
    nodes[2].data=15;
    nodes[2].next=nodes+3;

    //Четвёртый
    nodes[3].data=9;
    nodes[3].next=nodes+4;

    //Пятый
    nodes[4].data=26;
    nodes[4].next=0; //Следующего элемента нет, поэтому нулевой указатель

    delete[] nodes;
}
```

Comment: У вас не список а обычный массив.

Comment: Это список. Просто я создаю все его элементы одним вызовом new. Каждый элемент хранит указатель на следующий. Можно написать

    list* node1=new list;
    list* node2=new list;
    ...

 Это будет то же самое, но больше кода.

Comment: Как-то я отстал от жизни С++.

Скажите, а `nodes+n` работает всегда вне зависимости от размера данных?

Comment: >Скажите, а nodes+n работает всегда вне зависимости от размера данных?

 Да. n - это смещение не в байтах, а в размерах типа. nodes+n это то же самое, что и &nodes[n].

Comment: Спасибо) Всё работает, вот что получилось:

    #include <iostream.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    struct st
    {
    char name[10];
    int age;
    struct st *next;
    };
    void main()
    {
    int n;
    cout<<"enter the count of elements:"<<endl<<"n = ";
    cin>>n;
    st *list=(st*)malloc(n*sizeof(st));
    cout<<"enter data:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    cin>>list[i].name>>list[i].age;
    if(i==n-1)list[i].next=NULL;
    else list[i].next=list+1+i;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cout<<list[i].name<<" "<<list[i].age<<endl;;
    free(list);
    cout<<endl;
    }

Comment: "enter the count of elements" -> "enter the number of elements"

Comment: @Jonny-ice, этот код будет работать не с любым списком, а только если его элементы будут лежать в памяти вплотную по порядку друг за другом, т.к. обращение идет не как к списку, а как к массиву.